# How to store images like Images API

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, wagtail

Hi this my model for create simple member already searched for several places and until now I haven't figured out how I can store the directory of my image next to my **image** field.

```
class Member(models.Model):
with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))+'/api/data/states.json') as s:
    states_json = json.load(s)
    STATES = [(str(state["nome"]), str(state["sigla"])) for state in states_json]

name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Nome')
image = models.ForeignKey(
    "wagtailimages.Image",
    blank=False,
    null=True,
    related_name="+",
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    verbose_name='Imagem do membro',
)
role = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Cargo')
city = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Cidade')
state = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='Estado',
    max_length=19,
    choices=STATES,
    default=('SP'),
)
created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Atualizado')
modified = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Modificado')

panels = [
    FieldPanel("name"),
    ImageChooserPanel("image"),
    FieldPanel("role"),
    FieldPanel("city"),
    FieldPanel("state"),
    FieldPanel("created"),
    FieldPanel("modified"),
]

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Membro'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Membros'
```

This work normally but how to store image informations like Wagtail Images API?

Example:

```
"detail_url": "http://localhost/api/v2/images/2/",
"download_url": "/media/original_images/l8GlI3V.jpg"
```

This my **JSON** from API

`[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Gabriel",
    "role": "Desenvolvedor",
    "image": 4,
    "city": "Itapetininga",
    "state": "São Paulo",
    "created": "2020-04-26",
    "modified": "2020-04-26"
  }
]`

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: I'm adding a note that you'll need to use `uget_lazy` on your `verbose_name`, I'll try to solve this if I can rn

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Ty bro!

Comment: I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nH0UjdCNV7s&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub&index=39&t=0s) should help

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8.1/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html?highlight=serializer#custom-serialisers) is the link from the docs, Wagtail has a dependency of DRF, Create the serializer that you want and represent the image as a link instead of the pk, This should be straightforward (see DRF docs).

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nH0UjdCNV7s&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub&index=39&t=0s) video on custom serializers should help too.

Comment: Not possible to use serializer with models.Model?

Comment: Why not? This is the main purpose of DRF

Comment: Yes but I say pass serializer without APIField("author_image", serializer=ImageSerializedField())